# Rails attribute method for_database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes

I knew that there was an `attribute_in_database` ([ref](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html#method-i-attribute_in_database)) method but recently figured out that there's also an `attribute_for_database`.

I'm wondering where is this documented and what is it for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The culprit seems to be: [before_type_cast.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/before_type_cast.rb#L32)

Turns out Rails uses the attribute method setters itself to define more attribute methods. In this case the attribute is used just for taking the value before typecasting/serialization.